# shortcut not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-kepler

I am using **ECLIPSE KEPLER** for java programing. When I press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) it working fine and easily undo the history but the problem is when I press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) , this is not working to re-undo the history. Before KEPLER I use INDIGO it's accept above tags but how I reach it in KEPLER.

Comment: Did you saved the file when pressing Ctrl + Y or when pressing Ctrl + Y was editor dirty?

Comment: As I mention in question above , when I press Ctrl+Y , it should re-undo the history but it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Eclipse Preferences, then General->Keys .

Type 'redo' into the textbox and check if the binding is correct. If it is, then check for conflicts (they are shown in the lower right.)